# Apache Cordova App

Tags: javascript, php, html

I did an app for Android using Apache Cordova I came to the end that the program worked fine, but when I put the program on the tablet does not work, would you tell me why? The function of this app is the link to an altervista database

The error message is:

```
06-21 09:01:36.531 6705 6720 W System.err: stat failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/com.microsoft.office.excel/files/aria/offlinest‌​oragelow.db
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: there isn't an error

Comment: Sorry i'm wrong i see this one

Comment: 06-21 09:01:36.531 6705 6720 W System.err: stat failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/com.microsoft.office.excel/files/aria/offlinestoragelow.db